# How to add shared library dependencies to debian/control?

Tags: debian, packaging, qt, shared-library, opencv

I am trying to make a debian package from a Qt application relying on OpenCV.

What I did so far:

1. I set up an Ubuntu in a Virtualbox
2. I installed the neccessary software to compile and run the application (Qt related things, `ffmpeg`, codecs, OpenCV etc.)
3. I successfully compiled and ran the application
4. I created a GPG key
5. With dh_make I created the debian directory in my project dir
6. I added the packages to debian/control->Build Depends what I got by executing `dpkg-depcheck -d qmake`
7. I added to the Depends also what I got by dpkg-depcheck -d SampleApp
8. I edited the copyright and changelog files
9. I tried to run `dpkg-buildpackage -b`

At this point I got the error message:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1 (used by debian/sampleapp/opt/SampleApp/bin/SampleApp)

dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/sampleapp.substvars debian/sampleapp/opt/SampleApp/bin/SampleApp returned exit code 2

make: *** [binary] Error 2

dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

All these files can be found under `/usr/local/lib/`. I have read this: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html but I could not find the solution. How could I add these dependencies to the package?

#### Edit:

```
Build-Depends field:

Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), libpopt0:i386, libqt5core5a:i386, qtdeclarative5-dev, libglib2.0-0:i386, qtchooser, pkg-config, qt5-qmake:i386, locales

Depends field:

Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, udev, libxext6:i386, libxcomposite1:i386, libopencore-amrwb0:i386, libglib2.0-0:i386, libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386, libva-drm1:i386, libxinerama1:i386, libmp3lame0:i386, libnih1:i386, libx11-6:i386, libxcb-render0:i386, libffi6:i386, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386, libdrm2:i386, libvorbis0a:i386, libfontconfig1:i386, libxrender1:i386, libpango-1.0-0:i386, libdbus-1-3:i386, libpixman-1-0:i386, libopenexr6:i386, libxvidcore4:i386, libjpeg-turbo8:i386, libcgmanager0:i386, libcairo2:i386, libjasper1:i386, libxfixes3:i386, libilmbase6:i386, libtiff5:i386, libusb-1.0-0:i386, libdc1394-22:i386, libxi6:i386, libfreetype6:i386, libxrandr2:i386, libqt5network5:i386, libpng12-0:i386, libthai0:i386, libxcb-shm0:i386, libva1:i386, libvorbisenc2:i386, libtheora0:i386, libharfbuzz0b:i386, libicu52:i386, libjbig0:i386, libopencore-amrnb0:i386, libogg0:i386, libxcursor1:i386, libxcb1:i386, libraw1394-11:i386, libudev1:i386, libnih-dbus1:i386, libqt5core5a:i386, libgraphite2-3:i386, libva-x11-1:i386, libatk1.0-0:i386, libexpat1:i386, libgtk2.0-0:i386, libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386, libdatrie1:i386, libxdmcp6:i386, libvdpau1:i386, libxdamage1:i386, libxau6:i386
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the shared library you depend upon is installed in `/usr/local/lib` rather than `/usr/lib` (or similar) then I suspect it's not part of any package managed by the `dpkg` package manager. `dh_shlibdeps` wants to build a complete list of all of the things that your new package will have to depend on, but in this case one of those things seems to exist outside of any package so it can't be listed.

You should install OpenCV from a Debian package (plus its corresponding `-dev` package, so you can build against it), not from a local installation.